# Counting rows in grid using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application I have a grid, in which I have to count the rows. Below is the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="ext-gen156" class="x-grid3-scroller" style="width: 1024px; height: 216px;">
   <div id="ext-gen157" class="x-grid3-body" style="width:1005px;"> 
   <div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-first" style="width:1005px;">
   <div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt" style="width:1005px;">
   <div class="x-grid3-row" style="width:1005px;">
   <div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt" style="width:1005px;">
   <div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-last" style="width:1005px;">
</div>
```

I have also attached the screenshot of the grid (for which the snippet has been generated). Can anyone help me to find the way how to find the no. of rows.

I tried with the list webelement:

```
List <webelement> gridrow = driver.findElments(By.Xpath("xpath"));
gridrow.getsize();
```

Comment: If you use the correct xpath, that code should work

Comment: Please double-check your HTML snippet. It doesn't look like any but the outermost `<div>` tag is closed.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things that are wrong about your code snippet.

```
List <webelement> gridrow = driver.findElments(By.Xpath("xpath"));
gridrow.getsize();
```

1. Probably just a typo, but `webelement` is a class name, so it should be `WebElement`
2. You haven't included your XPath - once you do that, your code will work
3. To get the number of elements in the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you should call `size()`

With, `//*[@id='ext-gen156']` you can select the parent. Then you can do for instance

```
List <Webelement> gridrow = driver.findElments(By.Xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen156']/div[contains(@class, 'row')]"));
gridrow.size();
```

to select all the `divs` in this element where `class` attribute contains `row`. I don't really know the exact XPath expression you want to use, so I'm just guessing.